# Downgrade Google Chrome 7 to 6

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a webapp that used too work great when using Chrome 6, but when I updated to 7 it stopped working. How do I downgrade to chrome 6?

Comment: Just curious, which web app?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall chrome, and grab the version you want from filehippo.com

Comment: and don't forget to disable auto update ;)

Answer (score 1):

Force Flow's answer is perfectly valid but you might be able to find Chrome 6 packaged as a portable application making it possible for you to continue using Chrome 7 (and beyond) and still use Chrome 6 for the webapp which is causing you problems on the same machine.

[portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com) might be a good place to start although they only have 7 and 8 versions of Chrome readily accessible.